# Display % Symbol On Y-axis in SSRS 2008

Tags: reporting-services

Can I Display % Symbol On Y-axis in SSRS 2008?

Please click the below link for sample image of the report?
http://i48.tinypic.com/20ib1v8.png

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the value Axis and format the number to Percentage.  I would say this is the easiest.